# SQL Insert by from another table through a reference table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got three tables in MySQL: wp_usermeta, directory_department, and directory_departmentmemebership

Directory_departmentmembership

```
| employee_id|department_id|
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1          |        2    |          
| 2          |        1    |       
| 3          |        3    |
```

directory_department

```
| department_id|department_name|
|:-----------  |--------------:|
| 1            |        Deans  |          
| 2            |        MBA    |       
| 3            |        Fiance |
```

wp_usermeta has:

```
| employee_id| meta_key      | meta_value   |
|:-----------|--------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |department_id  |     2        |
| 2          |department_id  |     1        |
| 3          |department_id  |     3        | 
| 1          |department_name|              |
| 2          |department_name|              |
| 3          |department_name|              |
```

How I can I reference directory_department to insert the correct department_name based off of the department_id value in the meta_value field?

Comment: Just use the statement: `INSERT INTO … SELECT … FROM …`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html Or are you asking for the complete INSERT and SELECT queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL function to get the right name for each id...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_department](@id INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @department_name varchar(300)
    select @department_name = department_name from directory_department where department_id = @id

    RETURN @department_name

END

--And call it like this...
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (id,department_name)
select id, dbo.fn_department(id) as department_name
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! I'm trying this out now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly new to mysql. What exactly does [dbo] mean?

Comment: dbo (database owner) is the default schema, all tables and objects (stored procedures and functions) are usually created with this schema.